# Python - XLSXWriter writes character per column

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Assuming that I have the following code snippet and an ordered_list containing my values appended together, one row of contents which printed out on my test in this format:

> [text:u'LT4974', text:u'MRNAMEID', number:14, number:121]

If I didn't enclose the `row` in a `str()` method, a different error would occur. However it will result to an output file that writes every character per column... Which is wrong. How would I correctly write it in such a way that it will only get the following contents in their respective columns?

*COL1  ||  COL2  || COL3  ||  COL4*

*LT4974  ||  MRNAMEID || 14 ||  121*

```
new_workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
sheet = new_workbook.add_worksheet('test')

for row_index, row in enumerate(ordered_list):
    #for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write_row(row_index, 0, str(row))

new_workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

1.) If I try uncommenting the `for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row)` and change `str(row)` with `str(cell_value)` it would still write per character and this time not getting some values that falls as text.

2.) If I try to directly give row as in : `sheet.write_row(row_index, 0, row)` it will say an error TypeError: `Unsupported type <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'> in write()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I just made some modification from Vivek's suggestion. It should be `sheet.write(row_index, col_index, str(item))` instead.

```
new_workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
sheet = new_workbook.add_worksheet('test')

for row_index, row in enumerate(ordered_list):
        for col_index,item in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(row_index, col_index, str(item))

new_workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add one more for loop to write it into different columns as needed

```
new_workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
sheet = new_workbook.add_worksheet('test')

for row_index, row in enumerate(ordered_list):
        for col_index,item in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write_row(row_index, col_index, str(item))

new_workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

kindly lemme know if this change helps you

Comment: I'll try this one again. I've commented out the similar line as I've remembered I was encountering an error. I'll test it again as you've advised.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't figure the problem :( It still saves in characters and this time starting somewhere in the middle. @Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Check your source list, I had separated it by TAB and I changed it to separate by @VM, in my case (list), and it works!